# R mutate data based on multiple columns

Tags: r

I am trying to use ggplot to plot this data and color the plot by stage. But some Ids can have two stages so I want them counted in both stage1 and stage 2.
I was trying case_when like below

```
data <- mydata %>%
      mutate(stage = case_when(
status_stage1_a|status_stage1_b|status_stage1_c ==1 ~ "stage1",
status_stage2_a|status_stage2_b ==1 ~ "stage2")) %>%
group_by(country, stage) %>%
summarize(Total=n())
ggplot(data, aes( y = Total, x = country, fill=stage))

mydata<-
ID name country status_stage1_a status_stage1_b status_stage1_c status_stage2_a status_stage2_b
1a John Mexico 1 0 0 0 0
2a Lisa Peru 1 0 0 1 0
3b Amber USA 0 0 1 0 1
4c Jake USA 0 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should condense your data by adding all the stage 1 columns together and the stage 2 columns together, then pivoting into long format:

```r
 mydata %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(stage1 = sum(across(starts_with("status_stage1"))),
          stage2 = sum(across(starts_with("status_stage2")))) %>%
   pivot_longer(starts_with("stage"), names_to = "stage") %>%
   filter(value != 0) %>%
   group_by(country, stage) %>%
   summarize(Total = n()) %>%
   ggplot(aes(country, Total, fill = stage)) +
   geom_col(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")) +
   scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
   theme_bw()
```

[image]